# Cannot add Multimedia Widgets to Qt Creator C++ project

Tags: c++, qt, video, raspberry-pi, multimedia

I am trying to compile and run the official Media Player Example in Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html for a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie. I still have no success: when I build the project, the following error appears:

```
:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia multimediawidgets
```

This is referred to the .pro code:

```
QT += multimedia \
```

My Qt should be up to date, and I don't know where the problem can be. 
Could anyone help please?
Thanks!

EDIT: I installed "sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev" but without success. Is it the right module to install?

EDIT 2: the qtmultimedia5 packet seems to be well installed, but the "Unknown module(s)" error in Qt remains! Perhaps after its installation the library has to be added manually in some way? Please help!

Comment: You probably didn't build QtMultimedia module for your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I installed "sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev" but without success. Is it the right module to install? Thanks

Comment: I think it is not that easy, here is some discussion of this http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2013/03/bring-up-qt-501-on-raspberry-pi-with.html

Comment: Sorry I don't have Raspberry Pi myself and can't try it

Answer (score 0):

I have a raspberry 1 model B, and the first thing I wanted to do was a media center from scratch. Of course, in Qt.

Sadly, I struggled a lot before giving up and falling back on a omxplayer wrapper which I am still developing.

However, a few weeks ago gstreamer still did not support omx backend (so you cannot play decently any kind of media).

Note that you need to buy MPEG-2 and VC-1 licences to gain hardware accelaration for media, otherwise you can easily get very low fps (and bad audio) while playing mpegs and so on.

Take a look at [this page](https://twolife.be/raspbian/pool/qt/) for a recent Qt version.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Giancarlo for the feedback! So you mean there is no chance to manage video player using QtMultimedia features? By now, I'm still having problems with that, so I fall back on omxplayer too, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: I know, it is not a bad solution, you could try crosscompiling the latest Qt version against Gstreamer1.0 with omx backend (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-omx/)  but the last time I tried I had no luck...